# Can one be infected with Naegleria fowleri from Steam?

Tags: infection, disease, inhalation, sinus, steam

Will Naegleria fowleri be present in the steam molecules.

Many people inhale steam from hot water to get relief from sinus infections.

I [read](http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC242840/pdf/aem00217-0156.pdf) that Naegleria fowleri gets killed over 70 C. So will steam also kill it?

Comment: *I read somewhere that Naegleria fowleri gets killed over 70 C.* Where? (I’m not judging the fact, I’m interested in the reference). We are a scientific site, your chances of getting an answer are much greater if you document all the research you’ve done before. // Also, by Sinus you mean sinus infection?

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC242840/pdf/aem00217-0156.pdf

Sinus you mean sinus infection? Yes.

Comment: *To see how these data compare with those obtained in the semiquantitative tests, the ex- posure times for a 99.9% cyst destruction were extrapolated from the survival curves in Fig. 2 and came out as 65, 26, 17, and 3 min at 55, 57, 60, and 65C, respectively* (from your source). You would need direct exposure of 65 degree hot steam for 3 minutes to kill 99.9% of them. Not recommended...

Comment: Please click the "edit" link on your post and add the reference you posted above to the question itself. People shouldn't have to read comments to understand your question.